# How to divide multiple columns with each other in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 52 columns with sales data (weekly) and 52 columns with the sold quantity. I want to create another 52 colums with the price per soldunit.

The division does not work for some reason. I get

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Also, can this be achieved in a more elegant (pandas way) by removing the for loop?

This is what I have...

```
#calculate cost per unit
for i in range(0,52):
    cw = i + 1
    i = i + 5
    print cw
    data['Cost' + str(cw)] = data.iloc[:,i:i+1] / sap_data.iloc[:,i+52:i+1+52]
```

Comment: Please provide small (3-5 rows) reproducible data set and desired dta set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo of vectorized Pandas solution:

```
In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 8, (5, 6)),
                           columns=['amt01','amt02','amt03','qty01','qty02','qty03'])

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   amt01  amt02  amt03  qty01  qty02  qty03
0      2      2      6      2      3      6
1      4      3      7      3      7      5
2      3      2      2      7      7      5
3      3      7      4      4      3      1
4      4      6      2      1      7      3

In [25]: cols = ['new{:02d}'.format(i) for i in np.arange(1, 3+1)]

In [26]: cols
Out[26]: ['new01', 'new02', 'new03']

In [27]: df[cols] = df.filter(regex='^amt').div(df.filter(regex='^qty').values)

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   amt01  amt02  amt03  qty01  qty02  qty03     new01     new02     new03
0      2      2      6      2      3      6  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000
1      4      3      7      3      7      5  1.333333  0.428571  1.400000
2      3      2      2      7      7      5  0.428571  0.285714  0.400000
3      3      7      4      4      3      1  0.750000  2.333333  4.000000
4      4      6      2      1      7      3  4.000000  0.857143  0.666667
```

Comment: @NatalieL, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean just

```
data['sales']/data['quantity']
```

**Edit**: It might be a notation matter. Can you try:

```
data.iloc[:,i] / sap_data.iloc[:,i+52]
```

which I believe is what you have in mind

Comment: basically yes. but while shifiting through columns... as you can see, I tried to use "/". Which failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas [pandas.DataFrame.divide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) function. Is this what you're looking for?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales 1': [100,200,300], 'sales 2': [400,500,600], 'quantity 1': [10,20,30], 'quantity 2': [40,50,60]})
print(df)
       quantity 1  quantity 2  sales 1  sales 2
0          10          40      100      400
1          20          50      200      500
2          30          60      300      600
```

Creating 2 new data frames, one for the `sales` columns `df1` and the other one of the `quantity` columns `df2`. *In your case, you would have to set it to 52 instead of 2.*

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, :2]
df2 = df.iloc[:,2:]
print(df1)
           quantity 1  quantity 2
0          10          40
1          20          50
2          30          60
print(df2)
       sales 1  sales 2
0      100      400
1      200      500
2      300      600
```

Renaming the columns in `df2` with the names from `df1`.

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

Then, creating `df3`, a new data frame.

```
df3 = df2.divide(df1, axis= 1)
```

`df3` is the result of the division you need. If you want to have all of this data in one data frame, all you have to do is to rename the columns and [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) the 3 data frames.

```
print(df3)
         quantity 1  quantity 2
0        10.0        10.0
1        10.0        10.0
2        10.0        10.0
```